# Postfix has been hacked please help

Tags: postfix

I installed postfix and dovecot and set up SPF DKIM and DMARC and everything was running smoothly, till my Linode account reported high usage, upon checking I found a large amount of spam going out from my account. I have shutdown postfix.

#### Points to note:

1. Mails are going out from my domain `noidadeafsociety`, but the users are not created by me, these are fictitious users created by the spammers.

   ```
   sender_fullname: www-data
   sender: justin.f@noidadeafsociety.org
   ```

   The above user does not exist in my mysql database of virtual users.
2. Please note the following line in the header that points to a php script

   ```
   X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:isyfoyvr.php(1189) : runtime-created function(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code
   ```
3. I am unable to telnet to my ip either remotely or locally on the server via port 25

Below is the relevant portion of my `postfix main.cf` file

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = brahmaforces.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = $myhostname, brahmaforces.com, brahmaforces, localhost.localdomain, localhost, noidadeafsociety.org
mydestination = localhost

relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 31457280
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

#Append the following line for local mail delivery to all virtual domains listed inside the MySQL table.

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
```

Here is one message header from the queue:

```
$ sudo postcat -q A1E705E545
*** ENVELOPE RECORDS deferred/A/A1E705E545 ***
message_size:            2198             223               1               0            2198               0
message_arrival_time: Tue Oct 24 06:47:29 2017
create_time: Tue Oct 24 13:39:04 2017
named_attribute: rewrite_context=local
sender_fullname: www-data
sender: justin.f@noidadeafsociety.org
*** MESSAGE CONTENTS deferred/A/A1E705E545 ***
Received: by brahmaforces.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id A1E705E545; Tue, 24 Oct 2017 06:47:29 +0530 (IST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=noidadeafsociety.org;
    s=201710; t=1508832544;
    bh=6CNiZnlc0CH/LHm0VunVcXnxzPy9g3UAgtmu7mN62Yw=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:From;
    b=IO42NgZb1I7qjGaAQJL/Y0Dc4Q6Mv9WOCTPjGcCpFOtw/hPB4cf+PJXoAYmUCoyFG
     DSgVv1SqBx/W35pLLIedqciQhEnTlxbJCxKox2d7mIlZz6Vg5ywYlMbgJ/fBsZB+hD
     kJThn9Hex9a9OEL1ERZW5v8bxFpg3QY+A9jeizmX7FhQ1nLYwv5iLDP4FT+Qn6Zu3i
     9aRWSraMF+YplLwpUqzLWecZqB+9tUZHNZpC6eMg+UHFwrSSXbdDMtcmRFDDmmKnmG
     H5pHBqz86blZ6Ohf/ndca3KUqN+mo249lbo/5rq5pYyOESDwxiYNQy8MvZa8WYqIA6
     tsh23D6Ei1eWw==
To: sarcasticmute@yahoo.com
Subject: You're sleeping, and this program earns money!
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:isyfoyvr.php(1189) : runtime-created function(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code
Date: Tue, 24 Oct 2017 06:47:29 +0530
From: "Justin F." <justin.f@noidadeafsociety.org>
Message-ID: <79a51f9aa51cafb7505a4c92abc93109@noidadeafsociety.org>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.23 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_79a51f9aa51cafb7505a4c92abc93109"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--b1_79a51f9aa51cafb7505a4c92abc93109
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

There's nothing wrong to dream about the money that would appear out of nowhere. No one would refuse such happiness. But a dream like this, anybody especially was not true... until recently.

A group of German scientists are able to invent a program that makes money and allows you to forget about work and enjoy life.

It can bring you riches in a few weeks! { http://www.sriplasticenterprises.com/reduce.php?utm_source=67ksjr2535&utm_medium=ygapipe66p&utm_campaign=9h2vb6lp17&utm_term=5t9tgb2h6h&utm_content=s4mdh3336q } Come on click on the link and learn more...


--b1_79a51f9aa51cafb7505a4c92abc93109
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<html>
<body>
There's nothing wrong to dream about the money that would appear out of nowhere. No one would refuse such happiness. But a dream like this, anybody especially was not true... until recently.<br>
<br>
A group of German scientists are able to invent a program that makes money and allows you to forget about work and enjoy life.<br>
<br>
It can bring you riches in a few weeks! <a href="http://www.sriplasticenterprises.com/reduce.php?utm_source=67ksjr2535&utm_medium=ygapipe66p&utm_campaign=9h2vb6lp17&utm_term=5t9tgb2h6h&utm_content=s4mdh3336q">Come on click on the link and learn more...</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the spam emails sent as an authenticated user of postfix?  And are you securing your imap connection with TLS?  There are multiple certificates in play.

Comment: PHP is the probable culprit here. A common scenario is running an insecure Wordpress and having the spammers exploit the platform or one of the many insecure and possibly unmaintained legacy plugins. Postfix as such is probably simply working as it should. The `eval` looks like they didn't even properly break in to shell access, just found a way to pass mail to Postfix from an insecure PHP script.

Comment: A great majority of my clients come to me initially, because their sites have been hacked. Roughly 90% of the time hacks occur because of outdated LAMP code. Usually Kernel or PHP version. 10% due to WordPress code either being out of date or hackable code (theme/plugin) being installed from some place like ThemeForest. More than likely you're best off contracting someone to assist you resolving your problem, as cleansing hacked systems tends to be complex + time consuming... especially if this is your first time.

Comment: @bwDraco Any particular reason your edit reinserted the redacted spam body? Sharing the spammer's promotion does nothing to help clarify the question, and might help the spammer.

Answer (score 7):

Postfix has *not* been hacked. The vulnerability is in the `isyfoyvr.php` script, which has allowed a code injection. The injected code is sending emails, and since Postfix sees the emails sourced from *localhost* it accepts them as legitimate.

**Probable quick fix**

Remove the `isyfoyvr.php` script, or set its permissions so that the web server cannot execute it. Then reboot. And then check that the email spew has stopped.

**Proper solution**

Without seeing the code in question it's going to be impossible to identify the exact problem in the `isyfoyvr.php` script. The easiest route would be to go back to the place you got it from and ask for assistance there.

It's possible the script has downloaded a larger trojan, so I would recommend that you seriously consider a wipe, reinstall and restore from the last known good backup.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to also add **smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated** to main.cf and supply aliases for any official localhost outgoing mail such as "noreply@domain.tld"

Comment: I would say by the name isyfoyvr.php was dropped, and it was neither the original, nor is now the only way to get in.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro quite possibly. Really at this stage it's safest to assume the entire system is compromised.

Comment: @roaima In truth, we have not enough data to know. I have those "infections", and usually they are drive through  attacks, and in a *well maintained* system, they just go for the low hanging fruit, and usually only install a few scripts with the Apache user, more commonly to send spam/and or run ddos attacks.

Comment: I searched my Linode cloud system for the isyforvr.php file using a straight 'find' command and I found the file here: /var/www/html/noidadeafsociety/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/isyfoyvr.php  This is a wordpress install for a client. I have asked the clients web developers to sort out their wordpress issue. How can i REALLY secure my Ubuntu16.04 server, and specially my postfix, dovecot install. Also how can I secure Postfix so that it does not entertain requests from wordpress and any other sources. How can i  REALLY secure Ubuntu Postfix Dovecot.

Comment: A second question is since we know that a hack in wordpress can hijack my postfix system to send out so much spam, how can I reconfigure postfix  not to entertain wordpress or php scripts? I have yet to install fail2ban. Should I install antivirus software on postfix if so what? But more importantly what config changes should i make to prevent hijack of postfix.